# What is customer_note and customer_note_notify column in sales_flat_order table Magento?

Tags: magento

I want to know the significance of customer_note and customer_note_notify columns in sales_flat_order table ?

Comment: First did you tried to google it..

Comment: Yes i did search it in google and the answers that i found was not relavant...

Comment: So I am still wondering why was it downvoted?

Comment: I searched for it and landed on this question as first result

Answer (score 2):

customer_note is a comment which can be added from a admin side from sales/order. Then after can be call on frontend by below code on desire phtml

`<?php echo $_order->getData('customer_note');?>`

Answer (score 1):

**sales_flat_order.customer_note** is at least used when you create a order in the admin backend and is filled with the comment you give.

This is the result I got when I googled it.